# Open release of a personal attorney email to a school board

Tags: email

A school board gets an email from superintendent's personal  attorney restricting questioning of the superintendent. Is it legal to read publicly in an open public meeting?

Comment: What country/state are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it legal to read publicly in an open public meeting?

Yes. Generally speaking, a lawyer's communications to third parties or his client's prospective adversary(-ies) are not protected from disclosure.

From a legal standpoint, the lawyer's email to the school board is equivalent to the scenario of the superintendent himself being the sender.

Comment: Downvoted because ... ???